# Clickable link that fills a FORM field within same document (but with multiple FORMs)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm generating a long report that has multiple FORMs in it.  I want to be able to include links from within the form itself that can pre-populate select form fields.  But also support multiple FORMS.

```
  (html brackets removed)

   FORM id="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="..."   INPUT NAME="date1" SIZE="10" INPUT type="submit" value="Post" /FORM

.. data and links like
2010-01-01
2010-03-04
.. etc

 FORM id="form2" METHOD="POST" ACTION="..."  INPUT NAME="date1" SIZE="10" INPUT type="submit" value="Post" /FORM

.. data and links like
2010-01-01
2010-03-04
.. etc
```

I want to add some Javascript/html so that the date links can be clickable, and if clicked, they will populate the upper FORM field named "date1" with the clicked date.

The idea is you click on one or more of the dates and can submit each of the multiple forms.  I'm fairly new to Javascript and need to know exactly where to add which code to make this work?

I am aware there are some other posts about links to fill in forms but nothing about using multiple form IDs and wondering if there is a more efficient way and approach?

Answer (score 0):

I found someone on fiverr who could bang this out, paid them and might as well share..

Here is the sample code and solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple JS Request</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsRequest(formID, dataValue, inputField) {
document.forms[formID][inputField].value = dataValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="xx" method="POST">
<input size="10" name="date1" value=""/>
<input size="10" name="date2" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
<br>
<a onclick="jsRequest('form1', '2010-01-01', 'date1')" style="cursor: pointer;">2010-01-01</a>
<br>
<a onclick="jsRequest('form1', '2010-02-01', 'date2')" style="cursor: pointer;">2010-02-01</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form id="form2" action="xx" method="POST">
<input size="10" name="date1" value=""/>
<input size="10" name="date2" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
<br>
<a onclick="jsRequest('form2', '2010-01-01', 'date1')" style="cursor: pointer;">2010-01-01</a>
<br>
<a onclick="jsRequest('form2', '2010-02-01', 'date2')" style="cursor: pointer;">2010-02-01</a>
</body>
</html>
```